# JQ Outputting different elements on the same line

Tags: line, jq

Json output:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "id": "fcf9728ed6e94078bae9ffe200bf1054",
      "redirect": {
        "source_url": "www.1234.com/acssurgerynews/article/248345/transgender-health/detransitioners-received-poor-evaluation-when",
        "include_subdomains": false,
        "target_url": "https://www.1234.com/viewarticle/962270",
        "status_code": 301,
        "preserve_query_string": false,
        "subpath_matching": false,
        "preserve_path_suffix": false
      },
      "created_on": "2022-09-07T17:12:21Z",
      "modified_on": "2022-09-07T17:12:21Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "fac3ab84691b44219c270a5dd073e374",
      "redirect": {
        "source_url": "www.1234.com/advanced-and-metastatic-breast-cancer/article/248363/breast-cancer/liquid-biopsy-metastatic-breast",
        "include_subdomains": false,
        "target_url": "https://www.1234.com/viewarticle/942277",
        "status_code": 301,
        "preserve_query_string": false,
        "subpath_matching": false,
        "preserve_path_suffix": false
      },
      "created_on": "2022-09-07T17:12:21Z",
      "modified_on": "2022-09-07T17:12:21Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "0ae189027c574eedac22f854b4676568",
      "redirect": {
        "source_url": "www.1234.com/advanced-and-metastatic-breast-cancer/article/249807/breast-cancer/evolving-her2-metastatic-breast",
        "include_subdomains": false,
        "target_url": "https://www.1234.com/viewarticle/963856",
        "status_code": 301,
        "preserve_query_string": false,
        "subpath_matching": false,
        "preserve_path_suffix": false
      },
      "created_on": "2022-09-07T17:12:21Z",
      "modified_on": "2022-09-07T17:12:21Z"
    }
  ],
  "success": true,
  "errors": [],
  "messages": [],
  "result_info": {
    "cursors": {
      "after": "equIy9ku2FDvBVLy0avqNewCdepOQiaIaSilEIhBNwhHDIkcF5EjJkYqPwqeewvR5Rb6UO4LB5moBKoO9puoiyJ9QY_bidbcFtbpp60QzYEl_9Hls0jD_2oINTM_CWJPCBTvzmVu7LlUCNTB_UxXE-Ox6h8vuhE"
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm looking to output on the same line such as:

**.id,.redirect.source_url,.redirect.target_url,.cursors_after**

fcf9728ed6e94078bae9ffe200bf1054,www.123.com/123,https://www.123.com/xxx
fcf9728ed6e94078bae9ffe200bf1054,www.123.com/123,https://www.123.com/xxx
fcf9728ed6e94078bae9ffe200bf1054,www.123.com/123,https://www.123.com/xxx

Comment: Is `.cursors_after` really `.result_info.cursors.after`? If so, how is it matched to each result entry? Each line gets the same cursor after?

Answer (score 0):

Build the string you want to output, then use the `-r` command-line to emit that string as-is (instead of as a JSON literal).

```bash
jq -r '
   .result[] |
   [
      .id,
      .redirect.source_url,
      .redirect.target_url,
      .cursors_after
   ] |
   @csv
' json
```

outputs

```
"fcf9728ed6e94078bae9ffe200bf1054","www.1234.com/acssurgerynews/article/248345/transgender-health/detransitioners-received-poor-evaluation-when","https://www.1234.com/viewarticle/962270",
"fac3ab84691b44219c270a5dd073e374","www.1234.com/advanced-and-metastatic-breast-cancer/article/248363/breast-cancer/liquid-biopsy-metastatic-breast","https://www.1234.com/viewarticle/942277",
"0ae189027c574eedac22f854b4676568","www.1234.com/advanced-and-metastatic-breast-cancer/article/249807/breast-cancer/evolving-her2-metastatic-breast","https://www.1234.com/viewarticle/963856",
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/clXEI-BF05P) on jqplay

Comment: That works for a single record but multiple records will all appear on one line with a comma at the end. I've edited the question.

Comment: @user2193480, you need to show more input data

Comment: That's better how would I be able to remove the quotes and the ending comma from the output?

Comment: If you want something other than CSV, feel free to adjust

Comment: There isn't a trailing comma so much as a trailing blank field. You said you wanted `.cursors_after` as the last field, but it's is missing from your data, so you end up with a blank field.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new array per entry containing your values and then use `join(",")` to join all values on a single line. `-r`/`--raw-output` omits the quotes around top-level strings:

```
jq -r '.result[]
| [.id,.redirect.source_url,.redirect.target_url,.cursors_after]
| join(",")'
``

The difference between `join/1` and `@csv` filters is that `@csv` will escape any embedded commas in the value and automatically wrap all strings in quotes. `join` does not do any escaping and does not add quotes around strings.
```